# Is there any reason this cronjob would fail in cron, but not on the command line?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, bash, cron

I have written a little one liner that will email me when a list of files changes - I used sha512 to generate a list of hashes and then periodically check that those hashes still match.

```
*/5     *   *   *   *   /usr/bin/sha512sum --status -c /sha512.sumlist && echo "Success" > /dev/null || echo "Check robots.txt and index.html in /var/www as staging sites are now potentially exposed to the world and the damned googlebot" | /usr/bin/mail -s "Default staging server files have changed" example@example.org
```

It works fine on the command line with:

```
/usr/bin/sha512sum --status -c /sha512.sumlist && echo "Success" > /dev/null || echo "Check robots.txt and index.html in /var/www as staging sites are now potentially exposed to the world and the damned googlebot" | /usr/bin/mail -s "Default staging server files have changed" example@example.org
```

As soon as I run it as a cronjob though it emails every time it runs with the failure message instead of only when the sha512sum check should fail.

Is there something silly I have missed in a rush?

I forgot to mention that I am running an Ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 1):

After paring the one liner down and removing the notification aspects I discovered that I need to move into the correct directory before running the `sha512sum` command.

So it now looks like this:

```
*/5     *   *   *   *   cd /var/www; /usr/bin/sha512sum --status -c /sha512.sumlist && echo "Success" > /dev/null || echo "Check robots.txt and index.html in /var/www as staging sites are now potentially exposed to the world and the damned googlebot" | /usr/bin/mail -s "Default staging server files have changed" example@example.org
```

The file paths in `sha512.sumlist` are relative so the command needs to be run in the folder containing the files to be checked against. In my case this is simply `/var/www`.

Comment: Kudos for taking the scientific approach and posting the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to specify user, like `root`.

```
*/5     *   *   *   *   root    /usr/bin/sha512sum --status -c /sha512.sumlist && echo "Success" > /dev/null || echo "Check robots.txt and index.html in /var/www as staging sites are now potentially exposed to the world and the damned googlebot" | /usr/bin/mail -s "Default staging server files have changed" example@example.org
```

Comment: I don't have a user field as I have simply gone `crontab -e` rather than editing the underlying text files directly in /etc. I am on Ubuntu.

Comment: Tried looking for errors in `/var/log/cron` or `/var/log/syslog`?

Comment: Thanks for your help, but unfortunately there is nothing in the logs. I have figured it out though and provided my own answer against this question. Thank you.